# Saving XmlDocument to Azure Blob Storage, content reads 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'

Tags: c#, xml, azure-blob-storage

I am using an `XmlDocument` object. When I save the xml file to Azure blob storage it is successful. But when I try to download it from Azure, the content only reads "`System.Xml.XmlDocument`." What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
// ...content of doc omitted for brevity

using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc.ToString())))
{
    try
    {
        log.Info("Attempting to save file " + filename + " to: " + containerName);
        blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Error uploading file. " + ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doc.ToString() just returns the object’s type name.

You want the OuterXml

Comment: OMG! Nice catch!